# What are the difference between res_model, src_model and model terminology in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

These three terminologies can be seen in XML and python files, so can anyone please explain its usage, and what are the effects of these keywords?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<act_window
    id="act_test_test"
    name="Am here"
    res_model="account.move.line"
    context="{'search_default_unreconciled':1, 'search_default_payable':1}"
    domain="[('partner_id', '=', False)]"
    src_model="account.invoice"/>
```

In the above example code, `act_window` is used to create a window action of a particular model. Here it is `account.move.line`. That is `res_model` is used to define a resource model.

Now you have an action you need to call it from somewhere. To do that you have to define a menu link. This task is done by `src_model`. You define a model name and the menu link will appear under a submenu of `Action/More` in `form/list` view. In the above example, I have defined `account.invoice`, so the menu will appear under 'Action' in `form/list view` of 'account.invoice model'.
[image][image]

This is what I understood. Hope it will help you.